# Nodemailer with new elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I have this code in NodeMailer for sends email:

```
var mailOptions = {  
  from: 'test@test.com',  
  to: 'send@send.com',  
  subject: 'mail',  
  text:'test'  
 }
```

And I have this function:

```
    mens.message(params, (err, response) => {
        if (err){
          res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        else {
        if(response.context.reporte){
----------->  var report = response.context.reporte;
            response.context.reporte=null;
                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
              if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    } 
                    else {
                            console.log('Email Send: ' + info.response) ;
                                        }
                                      });  
                  }  

              } 
        });
```

How can I do that, this variable "report", that have a message, can replace the "text" attribute of the nodemailer?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the text with the new value

```
    mens.message(params, (err, response) => {
        if (err){
          res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        else {
        if(response.context.reporte){
            var report = response.context.reporte;
            response.context.reporte=null;
            mailOptions = { ...mailOptions, ...{ text: report } }; // <<<< CHANGE IS HERE
                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
              if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    } 
                    else {
                            console.log('Email Send: ' + info.response) ;
                                        }
                                      });  
                  }  

              } 
        });
```

if your node version doesn't support the `spread operator` then you can replace the `mailOptions = { ...mailOptions, ...{ text: report }}`, with `Object.assign(mailOptions, { text: report })`;